# DataGridView DataError event...what triggers it

Tags: c#, datagridview

So I have a DGV that users are entering data in.  The data should be numeric but I realize that blanks and alphabetic characters need to be handled.

I haven't put in any CellValidating or CellFormatting events so I wanted t handle this via DGV's Data Error handler.

I put the following code in my DGV, but iut doesn't seem to fire properly.  I get error text when running in Debug but it's the very technical "Syste,.Format Exception..." text, and I don't want users to see that.  I'd rahter they get the message boxes in my DataError event handler.

```
private void grd1_DataError(object sender, DataGridViewDataErrorEventArgs anError)
        {

            MessageBox.Show("Error happened " + anError.Context.ToString());

            if (anError.Context == DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Commit error");
            }
            if (anError.Context == DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.CurrentCellChange)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Cell change");
            }
            if (anError.Context == DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Parsing)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("parsing error");
            }
            if (anError.Context == DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.LeaveControl)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("leave control error");
            }

            if ((anError.Exception) is ConstraintException)
            {
                DataGridView grd1 = (DataGridView)sender;
                grd1.Rows[anError.RowIndex].ErrorText = "an error";
                grd1.Rows[anError.RowIndex].Cells[anError.ColumnIndex].ErrorText = "an error";

                anError.ThrowException = false;
            }
        }
```

So why isn't my DataError Event handler triggering on the error?  Do I need to put in code that forces it to trigger (I had thought it triggered automatically on error)?

Comment: are you sure the `DataError` event handler is attached OK? You should also try finding out the error to see if you can avoid it another way, `DataError` is just the last way for you to suppress the error and provide some message.

Comment: Is it proper technique to try using CellValidating or CellFormatting before DataError?  if it is I'll go that route, I was thinking the opposite.  I'm trying to become a more proper coder so if CellValidating is the better way then that's the path I'll take.  Thanks.

Comment: There are some errors will go through CellValidating first, but there are some others will be handled by DataError. Because `CellValidating` is fired only when user inputs/enters/changes data via UI with some involvement to loosing/gaining cell focus.

Comment: Ah okay, thanks for the help.  I'm experiencing adventures with cellValidating as we speak...but getting close to the answer.